# Search and replace content in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I realy dont know how I could have lived without searching the text of stored procedures [Can you search SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466130/can-you-search-sql-server-2005-stored-procedure-content).

The next big thing for me would be the ability to replace some text in a couple of stored procedures. Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT**

I use Red Gate SQL Search for searching now. Its nice but they should give me the update feature! Please!

Answer (score 5):

you can select the procedures like below :

```
select name , definition from sys.procedures inner join sys.all_sql_modules on sys.procedures.object_id = sys.all_sql_modules.object_id
```

now you can make a update query for this.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is for SQL2005, but in SQL2008 you can do this:

```
select name, object_definition(object_id) proceduredefinition from sys.procedures
```

Now that you have a query of the definition of the procedure, (I would) use it as a derived table (I'll call it T1 in example below)

```
select name, proceduredefinition, replace(proceduredefinition,'texttoreplace','withthistext') as newcodedefinition
FROM T1 where t1.proceduredefinition like '%something to search for%'
```

Now copy and paste the new code definition into SSMS and execute.

Answer (score 4):

One good way of doing this is to start using Visual Studio Database Edition for your database schema management. This tool does many wonderful things, including refactoring your database code and doing search/replace activities across your schema.

The tool is free for users of Visual Studio Team Suite and Visual Studio Developer Edition.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with scripting the procedures, keeping the scripts in source control, and then using search and replace in a text editor to change the scripts?

Comment: Quite a bit John. The overhead for one thing.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What overhead are you referring to?

Comment: Management overhead. Sorry, didn't mean to +1 you there ;-)